# How are countriesofeurope characters generated?

Tags: fonts

I'd like to extend the `countriesofeurope` package with some other not-european countries. When I open the pfb file in fontforge and select a country I get this:

[image]

How is that generated? What tool should I use to create a similar outline for a new country?

Comment: As interesting a question as this is, I'm not sure it's really on-topic for TeX.SX.  Maybe you can try  [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Well, isn't it about how to create a font to be used in LaTeX? Even if it's not a "standard" font, it's still a font. Anyway, I'll be happy even with a simple suggestion for a tool to use for such a task.

Comment: [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18165944#18165944) suggests that it was simply traced with a piece of software (perhaps `potrace`?) and then used in fontforge.  And I would say a question on how to use a font in TeX would be on-topic, whereas this is a question on how to create/extend a font.

Comment: Each country was generated as a single eps file (PostScript) which then build together a Type 1 version. The OTF version is a simple conversion of the Type 1 font, enhenced by the possibilkity of having ligatures for the country names.

Comment: @Herbert and the eps file was traced with something like potrace from a pre-existing picture?

Comment: With another program, I forget the name. I created the LaTeX related files with fontinst, if I remeber well.

Comment: @Herbert Ok, thank you very much for your comments. I'd ask you to write an answer but unfortunately it seems you can't anymore...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each country was generated as a single `eps` file (PostScript) which then build together a Type 1 version. The OTF version is a simple conversion of the Type 1 font, enhanced by the possibility of having ligatures for the country names.

You can also use `potrace` for creating an `eps` image of another country and 
put it into the existing font file. It is easier to use the `pfa` variant of the Type 1 version. "a" is a synonym for ascii. The package `countriesofeurope` doesn't need any modification.